# DAX FILTER only filtering what it feels like filtering?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a simple calculated table based on a FILTER. The only thing the filter does is remove all the dates from a date table that are after the latest date in the "Resolved" column in another table (there is no active relationship between the two tables):

[image: Filtered table and desired max value]

The table should be showing all dates up to and including November 3. Instead it shows all dates in 2022. Any thoughts? Been staring at this and trying to search for answers for about 4 hours...

Comment: Can you show me the 'DateTable'? also, MAX('OB Backlog'[Resolved]) is 11/6/2022?

Comment: Yes, DateTable is just a list of dates. And Max OB Backlog Resolved is 11/6/2022.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked the `DAX` formula for the calculated table based on a `FILTER`. The formula based on a `FILTER` is correct.
You should use the exact `Date` type on the `Table` visual, but not `Date Hierarchy`.
[image]

Comment: That did it. But why? Why would changing the display format change the data?

Comment: That was a rhetorical question. I already know the answer is "...because that's how Microsoft made it"

Comment: Yes, you're right!